# Factory pattern and class templates in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, templates, factory

I have a hierarchy of class templates.  At the top of the hierarchy is an abstract base class (interface).  I won't know which concrete implementation to instantiate until runtime, so it seems like the perfect situation to use the factory pattern.  However, virtual member function templates are not allowed in C++.

How can I achieve a legal design similar to the below in C++?

The individual concrete implementations of the IProduct interface as well as the concrete factories will live in different dynamic libraries, one or more of which will be loaded at runtime.

```
template<class T> class IProduct
{
public:
   virtual void doWork(const T & data) = 0;
};

template<class T> class ProductA : public IProduct<T> {/*...*/};
template<class T> class ProductB : public IProduct<T> {/*...*/};

class IProductFactory
{
public:
   template<class T> virtual IProduct<T> * createProduct() = 0;
};

class ProductAFactory: public IProductFactory
{
public:
   template<class T> virtual IProduct<T> * createProduct()
   {
      return new ProductA<T>;
   }
};

class ProductBFactory: public IProductFactory
{
public:
   template<class T> virtual IProduct<T> * createProduct()
   {
      return new ProductB<T>;
   }
};
```

Comment: What do you use the template parameter for?  As shown, it seems like you should just zap it.

Comment: @Zack, the template parameter is used as the type for a parameter of one of the functions of the interface.  I'll clarify.

Comment: As described, you're asking for instantiation trouble - somebody's going to have to instantiate `ProductA<T>::doWork`, `ProductB<T>::doWork`, etc, for all T required by the main program, and if ProductA, ProductB, etc are hiding in shared libraries, it may not be possible to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why can't you templatize `IProductFactory` on `T` as well?  That would get rid of your error, and it's no less general.  The client is still going to have to know what `T` is in order to call the`createProduct` method.

**Edit Re: comment**

In order to do this, you will need to just create a templatized function to create the factory.  So:

```
template<class T> IProductFactory<T>* getProductFactory();
```

Now your factory is templatized, the `createProduct` method is no longer a member template.  Not sure what your criteria is for returning a `ProductAFactory` vs. a `ProductBFactory` but you will either have to pass in a string to choose, have this be a member function of another class that would make the decision, or have multiple free functions but only expose one version or another to a particular client.

Comment: Yep, that's the only meaningful solution here.

Comment: I thought of that too, but isn't that just pushing the problem up to a higher level class?  Consider a client that wants to make a IProduct<Foo>.  The client still needs to get an appropriate concrete IProductFactory<Foo>, which means there needs to be something that can polymorphically create IProductFactory<T>.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score -2):

This doesn't need a template. Does that eliminate your problem?

Comment: Please elaborate... how do I eliminate the template parameter from the design?